# Upload files with PHP on FTP server (WinSCP works)

Tags: php, file, ftp, upload, winscp

I want to upload a file on a FTP Server (I use WinSCP). But I don't know how use ftp_put.

```
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$remote_file = 'readme.txt';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

I receive the file with a form (`$_FILES`). In `$file`, maybe `$_FILES['myFile']['name']` but I don't know what to put in `$ftp_server` and `$remote_file`. The server `http://10.XX.X.XX/myProject/` and my file, in WinSCP are in : `/var/www/myProject/`

Maybe the hostname is XXXX@xxxxx

[image]

**It works !** Thanks. The problem was the path, the good is : /myProject/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ftp_server` should be the host name you use, when connecting with WinSCP, like `"example.com"`.

`$remote_file` should be `"/var/www/myProject/" . $_FILES['myFile']['name']`.

`$file` should be `$_FILES["myFile"]["tmp_name"]`.